# Lock Windows screen orientation for fullscreen Air application

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, flash, air

Is it possible to prevent the reorientation behavior of Windows? (Windows 8 on a Surface Pro in particular.)

I'm already setting a few flags that I thought would help, but no luck:

application settings xml:

- `<fullScreen>true</fullScreen>`
- `<aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>`
- `<resizable>false</resizable>`
- `<autoOrients>false</autoOrients>`

... is there anything else I can do to keep Windows 8 oriented to landscape while my fullscreen air app is in focus?

Comment: What does `stage.deviceOrientation` report?

Comment: Write an ANE to do that.